# Data validation in case of copy paste

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I set up an Excel sheet with drop-down menus for some of the cells. The
user can only select values from that list. An error message pops up
when something is typed that is not in the list (via Data Validation Error Alert).

When the user copy pastes into the cells then validation doesn't work. How to make validation effective in case of copy paste?

I found one solution but it always return true.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If HasValidation(Range(ActiveCell.Address)) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Application.Undo
        MsgBox "Your last operation was canceled." & _
          "It would have deleted data validation rules.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub

Private Function HasValidation(r) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    x = r.Validation.Type
    If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True Else HasValidation = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you took the code from this page:

http://www.j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip98.htm

When Worksheet_Change fires, your code always refers to the active cell, not the target where the copy/paste operation is being performed.

Change

```
ActiveCell.Address
```

to

```
Target.Address
```

and see if that works.

Comment: Hi JP, its not working. If I put paste wrong data in the cell that has validation then HasValidation function always return false.

Answer (score 0):

The "Target.Address" worked for me as mentioned by @JimmyPena.
But the solution still brings a bug, that if one tries to add another validation after adding the above mentioned VB code, the user is fired with the amount of message boxes produced by the vb code which is applied to the number of cells (viz. You will have to click on "OK" of the message box provided by the VB code for the number of cells the VB code has been applied to.. If code applied to 40 cells then you have to click "OK" 40 times... phew..)
Can you please try to help to add another condition to help this?
Or the last way that remains to only add the VB code after adding all the validations.